# Spring mvc маппинг с якорем

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Имеем следующий код:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Есть ли какой-то способ добавить якорь на маппинг(не обязательно средствами **Spring**) чтобы в итоге было:

```
/#someSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Якоря обрабатываются на клиенте, поэтому единственным средством их обрабатывать является использование JavaScript. В своём скрипте можно в зависимости от того или иного значения якоря запрашивать асинхронно данные по тому или иному адресу, который уже будет соответствовать маппингу на контроллер Spring'а.